# Странная ошибка (cmd)

Tags: cmd

вписав данную команду:
`mklink /d C:/Users/pimpam/Desktop/dbot.exe C:/Users/pimpam/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/dbot.exe`

я получаю ответ:
`Invalid switch - "Users".`

В теории она должна создавать ярлык на рабочем столе, но не работает вовсе

Comment: Поменяй слэши на бэкслэши. Я в курсе, что у майков совместимость хрен знает с какой версии и всё должно пахать, но я им всё равно не доверяю.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте писать пути к директориям в кавычках. Потому что у вас есть пробел в одном из путей, команда как раз работает по разделениям через пробел и думает, что передаёте 4 аргумента, вместо 3-ёх

Comment: как именно в кавычках? вот так: `mklink /d "C:/Users/pimpam/Desktop/dbot.exe" "C:/Users/pimpam/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/dbot.exe"` или так? `mklink /d "C:/Users/pimpam/Desktop/dbot.exe C:/Users/pimpam/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/dbot.exe"`

Comment: Первый вариант. Каждый отдельный путь в своих кавычках

Comment: Та же ошибка, но я еще попробовал указать там директорию не содержащюю пробел, и результат такой же, та же ошибка